# How to make Identity Server return both access and identity tokens?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I need both because I have lots of claims, I want to store tokens in client-side database, use only token without claims (identity one, I guess) and on request I will replace the small one (which was sent, it has no claims) with big one, this way requests are not that big and I still can use claims for API access. Currently only access token is returned, identity token is null. Here's identity config:

```
public IdentityConfig(IConfiguration config)
    {
        ApiScopes = new List<ApiScope>();
        Clients = new List<Client>();
        foreach (var apiScope in config.GetSection("IdentityConfig").GetSection("ApiScopes").GetChildren())
        {
            ApiScopes.Add(new ApiScope(apiScope.Value));
        }
        foreach (var client in config.GetSection("IdentityConfig").GetSection("Clients").GetChildren())
        {
            Clients.Add(new Client
            {
                ClientId = client["Id"],

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,//can be moved to config
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret(client["Secret"].Sha256()) },//can be multiple
                AllowedScopes = new List<string> { IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId, "apiScope1", IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile }//client.GetSection("AllowedScopes").GetChildren().Select(a => a.Value).ToList()
            });
        }
        Resources = new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            new IdentityResources.Email()
        };
    }
```

I use token endpoint like this:

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:5001");
        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(client, new TokenClientOptions
        {
            ClientId = "id1",
            ClientSecret = "secret1",
            Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
        });
        var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestPasswordTokenAsync("ssAdmin", "123abc");
```

I wrote custom password validator because I had legacy system which had it's own implementation of auth, not sure if it's needed but just in case:

```
public async Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await _userRepository.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);
            if (user != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.LegacyPasswordHash))
                {
                    var hashedPassword = GetLegacyHash(context.Password);
                    if (hashedPassword == user.LegacyPasswordHash)
                    {
                        context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(
                        subject: user.Id,
                        authenticationMethod: "custom",
                        claims: GetUserClaims(user));
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (await _userRepository.CheckPasswordAsync(user, context.Password))
                {
                    context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(
                        subject: user.Id,
                        authenticationMethod: "custom",
                        claims: GetUserClaims(user));
                    return;
                }

                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant, "Incorrect password");
                return;
            }
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant, "User does not exist.");
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant, "Invalid username or password");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is hard to see in your code, but it looks like you may confuse authentication with authorization. You say you use claims for API Access, that looks like authorization to me, can you elaborate a bit more on what kind of claims you put in you access token?

Comment: Yes, I need them for authorization. Claims are something like - "CanUseThisApi", I define them in startup like this :
                auth.AddPolicy("CanUseThisApi", policy => policy.RequireClaim("CanUseThisApi"));
and add something like this above API:
        [Authorize(Policy = "CanUseThisApi")]

Comment: Why do you use the AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword ? One idea is that it is only included when you use the code flow?

Comment: Honestly, I was trying different stuff, and this one looked like it did what I wanted - it returned token. What should I use?